# How to reduce CPU usage of textdb?

Tags: database, web, hosting, cpu

Normally, my website based on textdb and use a low CPU usage.

But I notice when my website get visitors or traffic. A CPU usage was increased very quickly then it make my hosting account was temporary suspended from this cause.

So, I would like to find a solution to optimized it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it is better to have an actual .html or .php page linked together rather than have a blog based off a database.  You can use PHP include and just create unique pages to optimize your site.

Comment: Yes, I have .html page which content page and spin content in .html with spin.php.

I notice CPU usage increased very quickly when visitors connect to my site.